# upper bound - display

Tags: image-processing, upperbound

This is an idea I got in to my mind,
All the display devices(screens which have pixels etc...) have an **upper bound** for the  amount of various images they can generate.

```
as an example 1024*728 - 32 bit pixel display can only show (2^32)^(1024*768) etc... number of identical frames without duplicating any scene(view).
```

funny thing is, It's like we could pre generate all the films all the windows we have ever seen in our lives through screens etc...

the question here is can anybody use this abstract idea to create something useful? :D

Answer (score 1):

You're talking of a number about

```
 (2^32)^(1024*768) ~~ ((2^4)^8)^(10^6) ~~ 10^8^(10^6) ~ 10^8000000.
```

The number of atoms in universe is about

```
  10^80 // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content
```

I think that there is no way we could pre-generate all the screens in our life.

Let me formulate another question. From a number this big, what can we do to reduce it? How to aggregate similar pictures in order to reduce the complexity?

Another nice question is: what kind of data structure we need to store all this information? Suppose we reduce the number of similar images to 10^10. What kind of structure can handle so many different kinds of pictures in an efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

So given some extra information about the scenes you could generate you might be able to pull apart the scenes that no-one has ever seen.

So if you could take all the pictures out on the internet and the statistics about what was popular or viewed a lot then compute your all possible screens you could pull apart that was not viewed much.

With some basic rules about complexity of the image you might be able to come up with images that have not been seen before.  Think 80% flesh tones might produce something coupled with a variance to show range might render people naked. :-)

Of course the computation of such an idea is vastly outside our potential.  2^32^(1024*768) is in the superexponential range which is outside the bounds of reality.  I tried to compute it in ruby, and it just died.  It would have been fun if it had actually worked.  :-)

Comment: To calculate this number (2^32^(1024*768)) you need at least 32000000 bits in integer precision, or a float with a 23 bit mantissa.

Comment: Just as an aside I thought I'd try and compute how long it'd take to generate that many images.  I had to limit my computation to 16 bit images, of 5 pixels.  That was the max ruby could handle.  I then said if I could generate an image in 1ms it would take way longer than the estimated age of the universe.  We think the earth is 4.5 billion years old.  This number was 315,647 digits long!  Many times larger than the age of the earth!  This thing wouldn't finish before we were swallowed by a super nova from our sun.  And that's just 5 stinking pixels.